# Partnership vs. Limited Partnership vs. LLC for not-serious gamedev project

Tags: business

Me and one friend are getting close to releasing our first game to the App Store. Right now we're registered as a "partnership" with the IRS. I don't expect to make much money, and I have a day job so it doesn't matter too much anyway.

**In this situation, what would the benefits of registering an LLC be?** I really just want simplicity of taxes and legal stuff. The limited liability seems nice in some sort of crazy disaster scenario, but how likely is that to actually happen? We haven't hired anyone, and all our assets are royalty-free ones from the Unity Asset Store or similar. We've done all the coding ourselves. Our game is a straightforward, pay-a-couple-bucks-up-front, no in-app purchases or ads, type of business model.

Comment: This looks to me like a question to ask a lawyer. Here, we can help you with the gamedev parts of running a game studio, but the business and legal parts are probably things you'll want to ask experts in business and law, not experts in game mechanics.